# Python- replace last n chars of a specific section of a specific row found in a text file

Tags: python, pandas, replace, python-re

I have 1000s of text files where I want to replace a very specific section of text with a predefined string. These files contain data like this:

```
Type        Basemap                                         20221118202211
QSNGAGL1     20221120209912300111111  1B        Bus             O
QO1290BOB203871145   T1  
QI1290BOA0587611451145B   T1  
QI1290BOB2044911451145B   T1    
QI1200BOB2014411451145B   T1  
QI1200BOB2014611451145B   T1  
QT1200DOY385621145   T1  
QSNGAGL2     20221120209912300100110  1B        Bus             O
QO1290BOB203871145   T1  
QI1290BOA0587611451145B   T1    
QI1200DOY2932411451145B   T1  
QI1200DOA2517511451145B   T1  
QT1200DOY385621145   T1  
QSNFB  1     20221009209912300101100  1         Bus             O
QO1290BOB203871115   T1  
QI1290BOA0587611151115B   T1  
QI1290BOB2044911151115B   T1  
#(and so on... for ~60,000 rows per file...)
```

The first row is a header which only appears once per file. The spacing in the data is not consistent. The number of 'non-QS*' rows between each 'QS*' row varies.

I want to be able to:

1. iterate through each file
2. find each row starting with 'QS'
3. find the 2nd section of text in this row (the number *usually* starting 2022... This is a date range, with 7 numbers on the end representing each 7 days of the week with a 1 or a 0)
4. replace these last 7 characters of this section with specific text ('1111100')
5. save this as a new file with the prefix 'fixed_' on the file name (as to not overwrite original file)

I've thought about exploring `pandas` but I can't get it to read the data correctly. It doesn't help that on row 55,000 and on (in some files), there appears to be another column of data where a text string has spilled over to the right of its row. I also can't use a simple find and replace as these last 7 values could be any combination of 1s and 0s.

Using the second 'QS' row from the example above, I'd want '20221120209912300100110' changed to '20221120209912301111100'. Note how the last 7 characters are the '1111100' I desire.

UPDATE: I've changed the sample text above to include a differently laid out 'QS*' rows which can occur.

Comment: you should post the code you tried so far and focus your question on a specific task you are unable to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GlBj2k/1)):

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r"(^\s*QS\S+\s*)(\d+?)\d{7}\b")

with open("input.txt", "r") as f_in, open("fixed_output.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        line = pat.sub(r"\g<1>\g<2>1111100", line)
        f_out.write(line)
```

If `input.txt` contains the text in the question then `fixed_output.txt` will contain:

```
Type        Basemap                                         20221118202211
QSNGAGL1     20221120209912301111100  1B        Bus             O
QO1290BOB203871145   T1  
QI1290BOA0587611451145B   T1  
QI1290BOB2044911451145B   T1    
QI1200BOB2014411451145B   T1  
QI1200BOB2014611451145B   T1  
QT1200DOY385621145   T1  
QSNGAGL2     20221120209912301111100  1B        Bus             O
QO1290BOB203871145   T1  
QI1290BOA0587611451145B   T1    
QI1200DOY2932411451145B   T1  
QI1200DOA2517511451145B   T1  
QT1200DOY385621145   T1  
QSNGAGL3     20221120209912301111100  1B        Bus             O
QO1290BOB203871115   T1  
QI1290BOA0587611151115B   T1  
QI1290BOB2044911151115B   T1
```

Comment: thanks, this does indeed work for the example text I've posted. I have realised that the long number section can sometimes be the 3rd section in the QS row, not the 2nd as I stated in my post. For example: `QSNFB  1     20221009209912300101100  1         Bus             O`. I'll have a play with that demo.

Comment: solution is: https://regex101.com/r/d9KSLD/1
I replaced the `\S` a `.` so the regex is now: `(^\s*QS.+\s*)(\d+?)\d{7}\b`